# converting a CSV to 2d array

Tags: arrays, applescript

I'm trying to take one row of a CSV and extract one item from it here is some of the code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set workingFile to (open for access outPath)
    set theContents to read workingFile using delimiter {ASCII character 13} as list
end tell

set rowTwo to item 2 of theContents as list
close access workingFile

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {","}
set rowParts to (every text item in rowTwo) as list

display dialog rowParts

set secondItem to item 2 of rowParts


display dialog "The second item is:  " & secondItem
```

I get this error when the program tries to execute `set secondItem to item 2 of rowParts`:

```
Result:
error "Can’t get item 2 of {\"Date,Day,Zimmer,Graves,Randolph,Dempsey,Hannah,DeVaughn,,GSA 0034G,GSA 0035G,48' Trailer1,48' Trailer2,53' Trailer\"}." number -1728 from item 2 of {"Date,Day,Zimmer,Graves,Randolph,Dempsey,Hannah,DeVaughn,,GSA 0034G,GSA 0035G,48' Trailer1,48' Trailer2,53' Trailer"}
```

Can anyone tell me why that error is happening?

Comment: Can you post the first lines of the file? Makes debugging more easy.

Comment: Here are the First three ,,,,fw: 20,,fwd: 20.5,fwd: 2.5,,,,,,
Date,Day,Zimmer,Graves,Randolph,Dempsey,Hannah,DeVaughn,,GSA 0034G,GSA 0035G,48' Trailer1,48' Trailer2,53' Trailer
1-Jan,Sun,CD,CD,Leave,CD,CD,CD,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `rowTwo` must be a **string**, not a **list**, remove `as list`.

`as list` in the other lines are useless.

```
set theContents to read outPath using delimiter (ASCII character 13)
set rowTwo to item 2 of theContents
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set rowParts to text items of rowTwo
set secondItem to item 2 of rowParts
display dialog "The second item is:  " & secondItem
```